# Grothendieck Universe

Tags: category-theory, definition, grothendieck-topologies

I have a question concerning the Grothendieck's universe:

Let fix a GUniverse $U$. Is a $U$-set the same as a $U$-category or is there a subtle difference?

Comment: I guess $U$-category is the same as $U$-*small* category, which is a category having its set of all morphisms as an element in $U$.

Comment: @Berci: And what about the connection between $U$-sets and $U$-categories?

I think that I don't understood you correctly: Do you mean that a $U$-small category $C$ is 
characterized by the property that ***every morphism*** in it is an element
of $U$ or that the ***set of all morphisms*** in $C$ form a set which is 
contained in $U$? By the way: If the second holds: Is it a set or a class?

Comment: Futhermore, wiki says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_category_theory) 
that a $U$-set $S$ is $U$-small if $S \in U$. Is it possible that a $U$-category is a category such that the $U$-set is the set of underlying objects. Or is it nonsence?

Comment: It's the second thing you guess: the set of *all morphisms* of the category is in $U$. And of course it's a set; $U$ is a set and everything in $U$ is a set. That should be clear from the definition of a Grothendieck universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "$\mathcal{U}$-set" doesn't exist. There are terms "$\mathcal{U}$-small set", "$\mathcal{U}$-small category", "$\mathcal{U}$-category". Definitions of them may differ, but all variants are more or less the same as in SGA. Such definitions are listed in [one of my previous answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969550/category-of-functors-c-d-and-grothendieck-universes/2969601#2969601).